# Use an QObject found by it's QObjectName

Tags: qt, settings, qobject, qcheckbox

I have a little problem in my program. I have a config file put in settings. I pull from it the names of the object I need to be checked (these are QCheckBox).
I have this piece of code (It compiles and runs but when it's at "cBox->setChecked" it just crash):

```
void Preproc::on_tBtnManual_toggled(bool checked){

if(checked){
    ui->tBtnManual->setText("Systematic");
}else{
    ui->tBtnManual->setText("Manual");
    settings.beginGroup("Preprocessing");
    QStringList keys = settings.childKeys();
    foreach(QString configParam,keys){
        QCheckBox *cBox = ui->gridLayout->findChild<QCheckBox *>(configParam);
        cBox->setChecked(settings.value(configParam).toBool());
    }
 }

}
```

I have tried to put ui->cBox->... put it says that cBox is not a child of ui.
If I qDebug(cBox) I have a QObject(0x0) so nothing !

I'm a little new to Qt so maybe it's a simple thing.
Thanks and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that an object is found?
I don't think so (different name? wrong layout?). cBox is 0x0 when nothing is found.
However put a

```
if (cBox)
```

before

```
cBox->setChecked(settings.value(configParam).toBool());
```

and it will not crash anymore when it doesn't find an object by name.

Comment: Yes it didn't crash anymore but I still have a QObject null.
I checked the name and they're good.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the name (content of configParam) is correct?
you can try the search from QApplication

```
QApplication::instance()->findChild<QCheckBox *>(configParam);
```

the findChild method performs a recursive search, if the object exists in the hirachie, it will be found. if the object is not found, it could be:

- the object does not exist
- the object has another name
- the object or one of its ancestors has no (NULL) parent

can you post the part of the .ui file with the check box? it would be helpful.

Comment: Here is my settings.ini from where it gets its parameters
`[Preprocessing]
cBoxGain=true
cBoxMask=true`

Comment: `<item> <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout"> <item row="4" column="0"> <widget class="QCheckBox" name="cBoxGain"> <property name="enabled"> <bool>false</bool> </property> <property name="text"> <string>Gain Error</string> </property> <property name="checked"> <bool>true</bool> </property> </widget> </item> </layout> </item>`

I've shortened my code by deleting others QcheckBox. Also I always got the same null object with your code

Comment: you searched for "cBox" (ui->cBox->...), but the name is `name="cBoxGain"` try ui->cBoxGain (or `findChild<QCheckBox*>("cBoxGain")` )